# Add command to right click menu of Explorer

Tags: windows-explorer, context-menu

I have made a very simple `.bat` file that will create a text file of all the files in a `dir`. Now I want to add it to the right click context menu of explorer so I can create a `txt` `index` for a `dir` at will. I am unsure of the appropriate registry to edit.

bat file for ref

```
%CD% dir /s /b /o:gn>%CD%\fileindex.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

First, put your .BAT file in a convenient location and make a shortcut to it. Then edit the Registry by adding a new Key at HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\ for the shortcut; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449316/how-add-context-menu-item-to-windows-explorer-for-folders for the answer to the same question.

Answer (score 1):

Save the following as a .REG file and double-click it to import it (you can delete the file afterwards):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\index]
@="Create &file index"
"Icon"="%SystemRoot%\\System32\\Shell32.dll,250"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Drive\shell\index\command]
@="\"D:\\FileIndex.bat\" \"%l\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\index]
@="Create &file index"
"Icon"="%SystemRoot%\\System32\\Shell32.dll,250"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\index\command]
@="\"D:\\FileIndex.bat\" \"%l\""

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\index]
@="Create &file index"
"Icon"="%SystemRoot%\\System32\\Shell32.dll,250"

[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\Background\shell\index\command]
@="\"D:\\FileIndex.bat\" \"%w\""
```

This will add a **Create file index** entry to the context menu for drives, folders as well as *inside* folders (when you right-click a blank space).

The single-line content of `D:\FileIndex.bat` (you can change the name and path obviously but will have to make the corresponding modifications above *before* importing) is as follows:

```
dir /b /o:gn /s %1 > "%~1\FileIndex.txt"
```

Comment: @Karan- Thank you.  What are the changes that you suggest to the `.bat` file?

Comment: @TomRuh: Please re-read the last paragraph above.

Comment: @Karan- Can you explain the changes you suggest?

Comment: @TomRuh: The changes are obvious as you can see above - just use %1 instead of %CD%.